# Deinterleaving audio channels in a variable-sized Simulink signal

Tags: udp, buffer, simulink

I am receiving data from an instrument over UDP using Simulink's DSP Tooblox UDP Receive block. The data is a continuous stream of interleaved samples from 8 channels. I would like to view these channels in the Spectrum Analyzer block.

By configuring the receive block to send fixed-size signals, I am able to use this chain to process the data:

[image]

The reshape block reshapes it to [8,128] so each channel becomes a row. Transposing it puts the channels in columns, as Simulink expects channels to be in frame-based signals. The rest just puts it in a slower buffer (not really needed) and scales it to the proper range.

This works pretty well, but because the only UDP block I have available is the one that comes with the DSP Toolbox I can't do blocking reads. This means some buffers get dropped due to the slight clock drift between my PC and the instrument. This means that every once in a while a block of 128 zeros per channel gets into the stream and throws off my analysis.

I can set it to produce a variable-sized output, and the Spectrum Analyzer supports variable-sized inputs. This should get the whole stream smoothly to the analyzer without glitches from dropped buffers. The problem is that reshape requires a fixed-size input, and I can't find another good way to deinterleave the data.

Now that I've posted this I'm going to work on an S-function to do it, but I'm hoping there is a solution using built-in blocks that I am simply not aware of.

Comment: In varaiable size mode what would reshaping do if input size is not multiple of 8?

Comment: @Navan For this application I know that the packets coming over the network are always 1024 (8x128) samples, so the variable-sized buffer will always be a multiple of 1024. But you have a good point - in the general case there is no guarantee of the dimensions being a multiple of 8, so that explains why there is no obvious choice of block to handle this sort of operation.

Comment: It is better to write your own s-function for this. Using any other block would create a variable size output and might cause incompatibility somewhere down the line. If you want to try a block I think selector block would be a good option which supports variable size input.